# Suspected virus in my Windows 8.1

Tags: virus, windows-8

I suspect that I have a virus in my computer.
There is a large amount of UDP traffic in my network card, I installed Wireshark and there was large amounts of UDP traffic, all of them are from the same source and destination. In my task manager, my network usage was 7Mbps when idle, the graph was almost a flat line.
Wireshark captured lots of traffic, turning it on for 5mins will result in a 500mb file.

71225 packets in 5 mins

This is one of the lines in wireshark that came like the others

```
71225   108.841168000   10.239.1.22 239.200.20.154  UDP 1374    Source port: 47811  Destination port: 10000
```

My private address is 192.168.1.13

Once I tried to scan with Norton Internet Security and it told me that SONAR broke, I tried to press the FIX button but it failed again. I used AVAST to scan during boot time but there was nothing.

I looked up at the process monitor but there was very little network activity used by processes, but there was obviously medium network usage in the graph.

I ensured that Teamviewer, Steam, Skype, Chrome weren't active. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried running in Safe Mode without Networking and see if something is still trying to call out to that IP?  I would also run the Antivirus software in Safe Mode.  How to put Win8.1 in Safe Mode: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode

Comment: I installed anti-virus in safe mode
Set to boot scan(Scan before fully booting)

Comment: With or without networking?  Is this when you performed the Wireshark capture?

Comment: No, the network capture was before the scan

Answer (score 0):

What you are dealing with could either be a (screencapture)keylogger, or even a botnet (if it is indeed a virus).

What i would do in your situation is firstly use a program like [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER) to remove any programs that look "off" (i.e. windows tune up, PCProtector, or any other unknown names), most of the time, these kind of virusses and escpecially malware are installed by accident, while installing other programs, it happens you forget to uncheck a box with "want to install *malware program* too?".

After that, i storngly reccommend using the program [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org) to scan your system for malware and rootkits (while scanning after updating malwarebytes, it is safe to temporary disable your internet).

after all of that, make **SURE** you remove the threats in Malwarebyte's quarantain tab, and restart your PC.

If this fails, and you are sure it is a Virus affecting your PC (which sounds rather likely), your last option would be throwing [Hiren](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) at it, o your favourite preferred bootdisc.

If that fails, i'm afraid you would need to Nuke your harddrive and re-install.

Comment: This my Wireshark capture
I captured it for 2 seconds and about 500 packets came in
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2khw04atdxlflh3/wireshark2.pcapng?dl=0
I hope it isnt suspicious

Answer (score 0):

Virus removal needs to be done in safe mode so that the virus is not active while you are trying to remove it. If the virus is active while you are trying to remove it, it can lock the files you need to delete, restart itself, and all sorts of other unpleasant things. Spam the F8 key while the computer is booting to get into safe mode.

From there you have two options.

1) Run an antivirus program. Microsoft Security Essentials is a good free antivirus program. Malwarebytes 1.75 (not the new version, the new version sucks) is more aggressive than MSE and helps to detect malware that is borderline but not detected as viruses by many anti-virus programs. This is the automated technique for getting rid of viruses.

OR

2) Manually remove the virus using Sysinternals Autoruns to spot suspicious autoruns and to turn those autoruns off, then note the file paths and delete those files. This is the manual technique for getting rid of viruses. It is more thorough if you know what you're doing.